# Is it possible to use nginx to rewrite the URI as a reverse proxy, but retain it in the request somehow for the application to access?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx

I want to use nginx to reverse proxy to a service and rewrite the URI, but somehow retain the full original URL. Is that possible?

For example, if I have a config like this:

```
location /passthrough/ {
  proxy_pass https://service.com/;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

If I call nginx with something like:

```
curl https://original.com/passthrough/api/users
```

I want it to proxy to my service at `https://service.com/api/users` **but retain the original URI**, so that in my application, I can get the full original URL as `https://original.com/passthrough/api/users`. Is that possible?

So far I can get `https://original.com/api/users`, but it's missing the `/passthrough/` part.

The receiving application is built using spring boot if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix "/passthrough/";
```

to your nginx config.

In your application add this filter bean

```
@Bean public Filter forwardedHeaderFilter() { return new ForwardedHeaderFilter(); }
```

You can then access via

```
ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
```

or just normal `HttpServletRequest` if you don't want to modify it

```
request.getContextPath() //returns /passthrough
request.getRequestURL()  // returns https://original.com/passthrough/api/users
```

Comment: Thank you! I was giving up hope that this was possible, but it works great!

Comment: @ZJL no worries, I had the same issue a while ago, was super annoying

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`proxy_pass https://service.com/;`

to this:

`proxy_pass https://service.com;`

If you append anything to the proxy pass url then it will replace the part of the request uri which matches its location block

Comment: That will cause the request to become `https://service.com/passthrough/api/users`, whereas I do want it to replace the request URI, but still somehow retain the original URI for the application to access.

Comment: Thought you were already passing the host in the headers?

Comment: I am; perhaps I'm not explaining myself correctly. I want to proxy and rewrite the URI, but I want to keep the full original URL that was initially sent, **including** any parts that were rewritten.